# Loop through comma-separated tags in a table and make many-to-many-relation to match in a tag-table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have these 3 tables in SQL Server 2008:

Table1 - **Something**

```
ID    Title    Tags
---------------------------
1     Test1    a, aa, b
2     Test2    a, b
3     Test3    b, bb
```

Table2 - **Tags**

```
ID    Tag
----------
1     a
2     b
3     aa
4     bb
```

Table3 - many-to-many relation table btw Table1 and Table2

```
ID    table1ID    table2ID
```

Problem/question: I need some SQL that is able to loop through every Table1 row's comma-separated tags, search for a match in Table2 (Tag), and insert the relation values into Table3 ... like this result:

Table3 - many-to-many relation table:

```
ID    t1ID  t2ID
-----------------
1     1     1
2     1     3
3     1     2
4     2     1
5     2     2
6     3     2
7     3     4
```

NB! No match/relation between 'a' and 'aa', 'b' and 'bb' and so on. Only 'strict' match.

And yes - when I have generated the values in Table3 - I will delete the Tags-column in Table1 (since it is then no longer necessary).

Please help. I'm a hopeless novice!

And please foregive a novice for stupidity and naivety - I HAVE tried to search for a solution, but it is a bit complicated to translate this problem into a simple search term - I may have overlooked a similar question

Comment: Many examples and methods for turning comma-seperatd into table exists if you google a bit: for example from this site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: Thanks - but I have been there. And I do have turned the tags (commasep.) from Table1 into a Table2. But now I need the last step ... the Table3: Loop through Table1 - searching for match in Table2 - and if there is a match then put relation-values into Table3

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you already had turned it. But don't loop in SQL - it works on sets of data, so you just join your tables and results and use that to insert into what ever table you need/want. Use Common table expressions and temporary tables if you're not comfortable enough to do it in one go.

Comment: Dont be (sorry). I am very grateful that you will take the time to try help me with my crazy sql-problems :-) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Select * into Table3 from (
select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY Something.id, Tags.id) as id
, Something.id as t1ID 
, Tags.id as t2ID
from Something, tags
where ', ' + Something.tags + ',' like '%, ' + tags.Tag + ',%')
```

Comment: YES! Thank you. That solved the problem. And it is even a lot more simple, than I dared hope for. How can it be that easy?!? I looked for split-functions and a lot of other more complicated solutions ... Wow. I am very grateful. THANK YOU :-)

Comment: By the way ... I adjusted it a bit. I have 'is identity' on the id's. And I had problem with SELECT * INTO ... Only little things/adjustments:

Comment: INSERT INTO Table3 (table1ID, table2ID) 
(
SELECT Table1.id AS t1ID, 
Table2.id AS t2ID
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE ',' + Table1.tags + ',' LIKE '%,' + Table2.Tag + ',%' 
)

I really love this solution. So surprising simple. Thanks again :-)